# SpringBoot Quartz - How to run scheduler only on one machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz

I have two machines on which I run the application. I just want only one machine to run the scheduler. I'm implementing it with Quartz, but how can I determine to only run it on one machine? This schedule changes the information in the database and sends e-mails. I just don't want to do it twice. @DissallowConcurrentExecution will help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So then you are running in a cluster correct?  You need to setup the jdbc jobstore:

https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.7/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html

This will store job state in tables which is what you want.  Each instance will read from this connection and only fire as appropriate for your configuration.

Its not a small thing you are asking, but its also very well supported.